# Randomly select row of data using linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

hi there I have a table called word table. with the following fields: 
WordID, Word, Hint, Category. the table has 40 rows of data. I would like to randomly select a row of data that matches a certain criteria.
heres my code:

```
public List<WordTable> get(string diff, string cat)
{
    using(Entities obj = new Entities())
    {
        var qry = (from c in obj.WordTables where c.DifficultyLevel == diff 
                                                  && c.Category == cat select c);
        return qry.ToList();
    }    
}
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: check answer as you are talking about random i guess i am correct

Comment: is that work for you ??

Answer (score 1):

for random selection you can do like this ,

```
public WordTable get(string diff, string cat)
{
    var qry = (from c in obj.WordTables where 
         c.DifficultyLevel == diff && c.Category == cat select c);
    var list = qry.ToList();
    Random r = new Random()
    var element = list [ r.Next(0, list.count-1)];
    return element;
}
```